# Intermittent nVidia driver loading - ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system (Ubuntu 18.10)

Tags: wayland, nvidia-prime, nvidia-current-dev

Experimenting with bleeding edge drivers via [graphics-drivers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

Dual-GPU laptop, 
Ubuntu Budgie w/ `nvidia-driver-418` freezes the screen after about 15 seconds of logging, except for the mouse, so I tried nvidia-410 and 415 and it only sometimes loads.

`nvidia-settings` throws the error `ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system`

but loads with partial screen
[image]

[image]

`Linux skyhawk 4.18.0-17-generic #18-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 13 14:34:40 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
nvidia-smi
Mon Apr 15 22:46:46 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 415.27       Driver Version: 415.27       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 860M    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   55C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      2MiB /  2004MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

`dmesg`

```
    7.073081] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    7.073095] nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    7.073102] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[    7.073102] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[    7.077684] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    7.082249] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: base HW address: e8:2a:ea:2a:79:b6
[    7.085970] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain package
[    7.085972] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain core
[    7.085972] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    7.085973] intel_rapl: Found RAPL domain dram
[    7.085975] intel_rapl: RAPL package 0 domain package locked by BIOS
[    7.086116] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 238
[    7.086397] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    7.086451] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.PEG0._PRT.AR02], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psargs-330)
[    7.086459] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_PRT]
[    7.086460] No Arguments are initialized for method [_PRT]
[    7.086462] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.PEG0._PRT, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psparse-516)
[    7.186041] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  415.27  Thu Dec 20 17:25:03 CST 2018 (using threaded interrupts)
[    7.191194] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    7.214782] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    7.215491] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    7.215754] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  415.27  Thu Dec 20 17:06:08 CST 2018
[    7.221693] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    7.222538] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    7.223063] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[    7.248789] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20180531/nsarguments-66)
[    7.304472] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    7.340248] Adding 16670716k swap on /dev/sda3.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:16670716k SSFS
[    7.648887] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    7.648888] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[    7.648890] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[    7.663188] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    7.666364] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver in 8 mode, major device number 236
[    8.557995] audit: type=1400 audit(1555386280.076:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/ubuntu-core-launcher" pid=965 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.558489] audit: type=1400 audit(1555386280.076:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=967 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.558800] audit: type=1400 audit(1555386280.076:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oopslash" pid=966 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.559344] audit: type=1400 audit(1555386280.076:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=964 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.559347] audit: type=1400 audit(1555386280.076:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=964 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.559348] audit: type=1400 audit(1555386280.076:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=964 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.559949] audit: type=1400 audit(1555386280.076:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=969 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.562885] audit: type=1400 audit(1555386280.080:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=961 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.562889] audit: type=1400 audit(1555386280.080:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=961 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.562891] audit: type=1400 audit(1555386280.080:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=961 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    8.646060] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[    8.646346] bbswitch: version 0.8
[    8.646353] bbswitch: Found integrated VGA device 0000:00:02.0: \_SB_.PCI0.GFX0
[    8.646360] bbswitch: Found discrete VGA device 0000:01:00.0: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP
[    8.646491] bbswitch: detected an Optimus _DSM function
[    8.646502] bbswitch: Succesfully loaded. Discrete card 0000:01:00.0 is on
[    8.768143] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.768145] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.768148] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    8.857865] input: lircd-uinput as /devices/virtual/input/input20
[    9.205259] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    9.249926] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: link down
[    9.250014] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    9.254137] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    9.491467] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    9.504092] nvidia-uvm: Unloaded the UVM driver in 8 mode
[    9.532167] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Unloading driver
[    9.576143] nvidia-modeset: Unloading
[    9.612318] nvidia-nvlink: Unregistered the Nvlink Core, major device number 238
[    9.622231] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    9.729809] bbswitch: disabling discrete graphics
[    9.730246] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.PEG0._PRT.AR02], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psargs-330)
[    9.730258] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_PRT]
[    9.730259] No Arguments are initialized for method [_PRT]
[    9.730261] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.PEG0._PRT, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psparse-516)
[   16.142019] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[   16.150020] vboxdrv: Found 8 processor cores
[   16.168352] vboxdrv: TSC mode is Invariant, tentative frequency 2394440871 Hz
[   16.168353] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 5.2.18_Ubuntu (interface 0x00290001)
[   16.174679] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[   16.175038] VBoxNetFlt: Successfully started.
[   16.181035] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[   16.181313] VBoxNetAdp: Successfully started.
[   16.188978] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[   16.189288] VBoxPciLinuxInit
[   16.193576] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[   16.306057] wlan0: authenticate with 10:6f:3f:f8:d0:e4
[   16.310742] wlan0: send auth to 10:6f:3f:f8:d0:e4 (try 1/3)
[   16.313234] wlan0: authenticated
[   16.319871] wlan0: associate with 10:6f:3f:f8:d0:e4 (try 1/3)
[   16.324916] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 10:6f:3f:f8:d0:e4 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[   16.325876] wlan0: associated
[   16.355404] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   20.050713] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   20.300757] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   20.300762] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   20.300766] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   27.275341] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[   27.292838] nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 238
[   27.385783] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[   27.794598] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve [\_SB.PCI0.PEG0._PRT.AR02], AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psargs-330)
[   27.794606] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_PRT]
[   27.794607] No Arguments are initialized for method [_PRT]
[   27.794609] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.PEG0._PRT, AE_NOT_FOUND (20180531/psparse-516)
[   27.894229] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  415.27  Thu Dec 20 17:25:03 CST 2018 (using threaded interrupts)
[   27.900766] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[   27.901674] nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  415.27  Thu Dec 20 17:06:08 CST 2018
[   27.903901] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[   27.904954] [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
[   28.305317] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[   28.305318] [drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[   28.305320] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 1
[   28.315254] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
[   28.318040] nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver in 8 mode, major device number 236
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post  output of the following commands: 1. `mokutil --sb-state` 2. `ls /sys/firmware/efi/` 3. `sudo lshw -c video`  4. `lsmod | grep nvidia` and  5. `dkms status`

Comment: @Marmayogi It works after I reboot sometimes, so I reboooted a few times and it came up. Once it stops working I'll post those because right now it's loading nvidia oddly. I'm also curious if some of my channels were wrong (bionic/xenail) instead of `cosmic` in my apt sources and maybe that was conflicting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears in `/etc/apt/sources.d/` there were a bunch of files referencing the wrong channel (by channel, I mean distro version, so trusty/xenial/cosmic/disco etc), so cleaning those up by hand (making them all the CORRECT channel via `sed`) 
E.g., bionic to cosmic:

```
sudo sed -i -- 's/bionic/cosmic/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
sudo sed -i -- 's/xenial/cosmic/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

then running

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

Basically put the system back in a stable state